# Name of PHP function

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function that replaces `-` with `_` (underscores) ?

Like

```
my-name
```

with

```
my_name
```

Comment: str_replace http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

Comment: which one should I use??

Comment: write your own function as they wrote above. we dont know what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the return of str_replace!

```
$name = str_replace('-', '_', $name);
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_replace('-', '_', $name)`

Answer (score 0):

There's, but it's not called replace_hyphen, it's str_replace

`str_replace('-', '_', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
str_replace("-", "_", "my-name");
```